# ¿Cómo recuperar datos generados por el método 'push()' en firebase database usando Android Studio?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Si registro datos en la base de datos... tengo la siguiente eferencia:

```
DatabaseReference  crearUsuario = databaseRef.child(Usuarios).push();
crearUsuario.child("nombre").setValue("Tony");
crearUsuario.child("email").setValue("tony@mail.com");
crearUsuario.child("tel").setValue("123456789");
```

Para localizar a dicho usuario hago lo siguiente:

```
 databaseRef.child(Usuarios).orderBychild("email").equalTo("tony@mail.com").addValueEventListener...
```

Pero si quiero obtener el valor del "nombre", Cómo lo hago si no conozco la carpeta (child) que me generó el método push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resuelto]:  En lugar de

```
addValueEventListener(...) {...
```

Es

```
addChildEventListener(...) {...
```

Así que...

```
databaseRef.child(Usuarios).orderBychild("email").equalTo("tony@mail.com").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {...

Strin nombre = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue().toString;
```

Yo creo que el problema era que  'addValueEventListener...'  hacia una escucha hacia todos los posibles 'Users' y no devolvía los valores de uno en concreto.

Al contrario  'addChildEventListener()...' nos devuelve los valores de un único 'User'.

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar el push habrás generado un registro similar a este:

```
-L3rXsR4HtgtfY1a3H9M
  nombre: "Tony"
  email: "tony@mail.com"
  tel: "123456789
```

Si guardas la clave (crearUsuario.getKey()) podrías acceder así:

```
databaseRef.child(Usuarios).child(usuarioKey).child("nombre").addValueEventListener...
```

No obstante, con la query que estás realizando, como bien dices accedes al usuario y desde ahí puedes obtener sus hijos nombre, email y tel:

```
databaseRef.child(Usuarios).orderBychild("email").equalTo("tony@mail.com").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String nombre = dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Introduzco los datos en una actividad (Registro) y las recupero desde otra (Ingreso al perfil). Así que no guardo la clave(crearUsuario.getKey).  Necesito algo similar a la seguda opción. Pero dataSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class);  me devuelve  "null". Por qué será? Si los datos existen!